# Writing output to different columns of a file

Tags: c++

Hi I was wondering if there is any function library that lets me do this conveniently or if you have any suggestions as to how I might do this elegantly without writing lines and lines of code (which is what I ended up doing with ofstream).

```
Loop over i
   Loop over j
      Evaluate f(i*alpha,j);
      Write f to column i;
```

Something like this. I need to compare a hundred different eigenfunction of a QM problem and I rather not write a file per value of alpha, will make plotting easier as well.

I did google without any usuable results, appreciate any help :)

Comment: `ofstream` should be able to do this without "lines and lines" of code.  Can you post up what you tried?

Comment: @chad unfortunantly not yet, I am on my ipod on a train and won't be home for another 6 hours and can't get this out of my head.

Comment: Can you logically keep your data laid out in appropriate columns in memory, then dump the entire thing to a file in one operation?

Comment: @Chad: Sounds like a very legacy DBMS we had to combat against at an older job of mine. Don't do that, it causes a lot of frustration. One example: How do read an older version's flat file when it has a different layout than the current version of the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your algorithm lets you to do this, refactor the loop to write row-wise:

```
Loop over j {
    Loop over i {
        Evaluate f(i*alpha, j);
        Write f to column i, <TAB>;
    }
    Write <CR><LF>
}
```

Comment: Then I would need to somehow go back to coloumns because of the way gnuplot is set up, it can only data coloumn vs coloumn

Answer (score 3):

Is your problem the aligned, tabular output, i.e. to visually have columns, or to be able to write e.g. the 4th field, and after that the 2nd one?

As for the former: Minimal C++ solution uses `<iomanip>`.

Assume you have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

struct Date     { int year, month, day;
                  Date(int year, int month, int day)
                      : year(year), month(month), day(day) {}
                };
struct Time     { int hour, minute, second;
                  Time (int hour, int minute, int second)
                      : hour(hour), minute(minute), second(second){}
                };
struct Birthday { Date date;
                  Time time;
                  Birthday (Date date, Time time)  : date(date), time(time) {}
                };

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &ofs, Time const &rhs) {
    using std::setw;
    return ofs << std::setfill('0')
               << setw(2) << rhs.hour << ':'
               << setw(2) << rhs.minute << ':'
               << setw(2) << rhs.second;
}
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &ofs, Date const &rhs) {
    using std::setw;
    return ofs << std::setfill('0')
               << setw(4) <<  rhs.year << '-'
               << setw(2) << rhs.month << '-'
               << setw(2) << rhs.day;
}
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &ofs, Birthday const &rhs) {
    return ofs << rhs.date << ' ' << rhs.time;
}


struct Dude {
    std::string first_name;
    std::string last_name;
    Birthday    birthday;
    Dude (std::string const &f, std::string const &l, Birthday const &b)
        : first_name(f), last_name(l), birthday(b) {}
};
```

Then you can output a simple table like this:

```
int main () {
    using std::setw;

    std::vector<Dude> d;
    d.push_back (Dude("John", "Doe",        Birthday(Date(1980,12,11),Time(6,45,0))));
    d.push_back (Dude("Max",  "Mustermann", Birthday(Date(1980,12,11),Time(6,45,0))));

    std::cout << std::left;

    // Output a fancy header.
    std::cout << std::setfill(' ')
              << setw(24) << "<last name>" << "| "
              << setw(16)  << "<first name>" << "| "
              << "birthday" << '\n';

    // Data output follows. Note: No lines of lines and code.
    for (std::vector<Dude>::iterator it=d.begin(), end=d.end(); it!=end; ++it) {
        std::cout << std::setfill(' ')
                  << setw(24) << it->last_name << "| "
                  << setw(16) << it->first_name << "| "
                  << it->birthday  << '\n';
    }

}
```

Comment: So, you're keeping everything in memory in a logical location, then writing it all out to the file in one operation ;)

Comment: My problem is to simply have raw data (doubles) in different coloumns. I will try your approach when I get home and hopefully I can just try the last part without having to build a struct for my data.

Comment: @Chad: I assume a sequence of data-rows. And iostreams are sequential streams, so they fit for them. I am unsure tho about what exactly you need.

Comment: @user948652: I assume you are @Chad? It is confusing if you post from different accounts ;)

Comment: Nope, he's not me.  :)  He just had the same idea presented more clearly.

Comment: @Chad: I beg your pardon, I was too fast to judge :P